# Modify text before pasting in X-window

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

When I punch in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, I don't want the system to just paste information from the clipboard. I want to do something with this information (e.g., delete something or modify something in it) and then paste the modified version into the field. Now I'm trying to write something like this:

```
if [ condition ]; then
    xclip -selection clipboard -o|sed "s/something/another/g"|xclip -selection clipboard -i
fi
xdotool key --window $(xdotool getactivewindow) ctrl+v #mimic Ctrl+V keystroke
```

It works very well. But the problem is that I cannot bind the script to the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, otherwise it seems to be cycling all the time (because there is always a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in the end). Is there any method to get around it? For example, executing an app just like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> so I don't need to mimic the system <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> combination?

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck. I've been doing this using Autokey for a long time.

First install autokey and python-tk:

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk python-tk
```

Now, start Autokey and create a new `script`. Write the following code in the script:

```python
from Tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
text = root.clipboard_get() + "MODIFIED"

keyboard.send_keys(text)
```

Now, click on the `Set` button for the `Hotkey` option. Here you can set your hotkey to <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>. It works perfectly. What's even more cool is that you can also set the Window filter so that this behavior of <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> is available only on specific windows; on the rest it will behave normally.